# How to insert character into a list before specific character from the end of the list and the same after last character?

Tags: python

I have a generated list for simple calculator.
It looks like this for example:

```
l = [1,5, +, 2, 7, *, 3, 5, - , 9, 5, +, 4,5,6]
```

And in the input line it will be looking like this  "15 + 27 * 35 - 95 + 456".

What I need to do is to implement a function which makes last entry negative and in parentheses (-456) ( not last digit 6, but all digits after non digit character from the end of the list)

So I have a list

```
list = [1,5, +, 2, 7, *, 3, 5, -, 9, 5, +, 4, 5, 6]
```

And I need to insert parentheses after "+" from the end, then "-", then 4,5,6, then parentheses again. 
So my new list should look like this:

```
list2 = [1, 5, +, 2, 7, *, 3, 5, - , 9, 5, +, (,-,4,5,6,)]
```

Basically I need to find non digit character from the end, insert two characters "(", "-", then add ")" after last digit.

How can I do this?

then I'll apply this function  ''.join(map(str,list)) and it will look like this  "15 + 27 * 35 - 95 + (-456)"

I've tried to use regex, but seems like I've failed :-(

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not use `list` as name variable, as there is built-in `list` function.
You might use `re` module as already noted, but if you do not wish to use it you might harness `str` method `rsplit`:

```
formula = '15 + 27 * 35 - 95 + 456'
parts = formula.rsplit(' + ',1) # note spaces around +
print(parts) # ['15 + 27 * 35 - 95', '456']
output = parts[0] + ' + (-' + parts[1] + ')'
print(output) # 15 + 27 * 35 - 95 + (-456)
```

2nd argument of `rsplit` is number of cuts, here `1`, i.e. split at last `' + '` inside `formula`. This gives `list` with 2 `str`s, which then I concatenate using `+` operator.

EDIT: As noted there might be something other than `+`, but we can use harness fact that there are spaces following way:

```
formula = '15 + 27 * 35 - 95 * 456'
parts = formula.rsplit(' ',2)
print(parts) # ['15 + 27 * 35 - 95', '*', '456']
output = parts[0] + ' ' + parts[1] + ' (-' + parts[2] + ')'
print(output) # 15 + 27 * 35 - 95 * (-456)
```

Comment: This works for me only when I convert my list into a string. I can do this and then convert returned string back to list again. 
But is there any way to make it directly with list without converting it into string? 
Thanks

Comment: is it possible to work directly with this list: 
formula = ["1","5", "+", "2", "7", "*", "3", "5", "-", "9", "5", "+", "4", "5", "6"]

And please notice that instead of " + " there can be " - " or " * ", or " / " 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
formula = "15 + 27 * 35 - 95 + 456"
new_formula = re.sub(r"(\d+)$", r"(-\1)", formula)
```

Comment: This works for me either when I convert my list into a string. I can do this and then convert returned string back to list again. 
But is there any way to make it directly with list without converting it into string? 
Thanks